# How do I make a button be disabled after one click no javascript HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a button unclickable after it is clicked once, but I don't want to use JS. Here's the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button>Click here</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want it to be unclickable after I touch it once.

Comment: You can't without javascript.

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll just make it with Javascript. Also, that's not even the real code, it's just an example.

Comment: Being pedantic, it is possible without javascript, but the solution is way worse. Submit a form and then on response, use the serverside language to add the `disabled` attribute. See, I told you it was worse.

Comment: OK now I'll be more helpful, what does the button do besides make itself unclickable? Does it it have to actually by a button?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible without javascript. Css has no control over the button's attributes and can't change the DOM.

This is the simplest way:

```html
<button onclick="this.disabled = true">Click here</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hacky at best and only kind of does what you want. It also doesn't use a `button`

We have a label styled as a button. Associated with the label is a hidden checkbox. When the label is clicked, the checkbox is checked. Once the checkbox is checked we have a CSS selector with `pointer-events:none;` on the label. Now you can't click it again.

```css
.imaButton label {
  background: #3498db;
  
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3498db, #2980b9);  
  border-radius: 28px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.imaButton label:hover {
  background: #3cb0fd;  
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3cb0fd, #3498db);
  text-decoration: none;
}

.imaButton label:active {
  color:#CCC;
}

.imaButton input {display:none;}

.imaButton input:checked ~ label {pointer-events:none;}
```

```html
<div class="imaButton">
  <input type="checkbox" id="btn"><label for="btn">I'm a button</label>
</div>
```

Javascript is a much better option.

Comment: Yeah man I tought about using a radio button as well. I just tought this would be the ultimate hack and I omitted that information so OP doesn't go around creating little monsters.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'll just try Javascript.

Comment: @Phiter yup compared to the single line of javascript, it's a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```js
function a(button) {
button.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="a(this)">Click here</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**If you want a shorter one, see the code given below.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <button onclick="this.disabled=true;">Click here</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_disabled.asp) for more information.

Comment: You've missed the part where it says "no javascript" in the question. You should specify why you're using it in your answer. Also, your second option is identical to an existing answer, which, at least, proposes it is not possible without javascript.